# Why does console.log log different results when I log string + object

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently trying to solve a problem in my code. For that I'm logging the objects and add a text in front to be sure where the log is coming from. Like these two examples:

```
console.log('TodoList Dialog Open: ' + todo);
console.log('Todo List get Todos ' + data);
```

When I log out the two examples above I get this output:

`Todo List get Todos [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Without any string in front I get this output:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 392, taskName: "GMDU", dueDate: "2019-02-07", extraNote: "You have done it all wrong", taskCompleted: true}
1: {id: 391, taskName: "PMB", dueDate: "2019-02-07", extraNote: "Study you lazy ass!", taskCompleted: true}
2: {id: 393, taskName: "INMA", dueDate: "2019-02-07", extraNote: "Do something else", taskCompleted: false}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Is there a way to log the objects and prepend a string to it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the first you defined string and then appended object using `+` concatenation operator so its convert object to string that's why you are getting output like that

To solve your problem you need use `,` instead of +

```
console.log('TodoList Dialog Open: ' , todo);
console.log('Todo List get Todos ' , data);
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace the `+` with a comma `,`

```js
const arr = [{
  id: 392,
  taskName: "GMDU",
  dueDate: "2019-02-07",
  extraNote: "You have done it all wrong",
  taskCompleted: true
}, {
  id: 391,
  taskName: "PMB",
  dueDate: "2019-02-07",
  extraNote: "Study you lazy ass!",
  taskCompleted: true
}, {
  id: 393,
  taskName: "INMA",
  dueDate: "2019-02-07",
  extraNote: "Do something else",
  taskCompleted: false
}];

console.log('The first object is', arr[0]);
console.log('The whole array is', arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` can take any number of arguments so you can put all data you need to log separating it by commas.

Try this:

```
console.log('TodoList Dialog Open: ', todo);
console.log('Todo List get Todos ', data);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/g4yua39k/1/) is a working fiddle based on your object structure. Check the output in console tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('TodoList Dialog Open: ' + todo);
console.log('Todo List get Todos ' + data);

// Here you use + to concat a string which is actually php syntax you have to change '+' sing with ',' 

console.log('TodoList Dialog Open: ' + todo);
console.log('Todo List get Todos ' + data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are trying to combine then as a string, instead of this you need to separate then by `,`

console.log('Todo List get Todos ' , data);